# XAML GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding does not seem to work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, gridview

I am trying to create a two column ListView with a data binding.
The XAML looks like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="BookingVariantsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding BookingVariants}" SelectionChanged="BookingVariantsListView_SelectionChanged" DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Top">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static loc:Settings.VariantTitle}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}" Width="320" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static loc:Settings.VariantLink}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding BookingVariantURL}" Width="315" />
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

and the model like this:

```
public class BookingVariant
{

    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("booking_variant_url")]
    public string BookingVariantURL { get; set; }

}
```

it is hold in a list:

```
public ObservableCollection<BookingVariant> BookingVariants { get; private set; }
```

Now the list binding seems to work, as it fills the correct number of rows. But the columns are not filled. Instead each row just shows the name of the class once. The columns are completely ignored as it seems.

Someone got an idea?
Thanks!

Edit:

The Listview currently looks like this:
[image: current faulty listview rows]

Answer (score 3):

I found my mistake:

At the top of my window I was importing another XAML file which contains style infos for others controls in that window (list views as well). When removing the file, the Gridview binding works as expected. So my own styles override the behaviour.
I will now assign keys to all styles so that they dont get used automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot to set the data context. The view control does not know where to look for the binding data.

Set the data context to the object that contains the ObservableCollection.

The source containing class

```
public class MyData
{
    // I dont know your class structure so I added all data in the constructor
    public MyData()
    {   
        BookingVariants = new ObservableCollection<BookingVariant>();
        this.BookingVariants.Add(new BookingVariant() 
        { Title = "Title", BookingVariantURL = "myURL" });

        this.BookingVariants.Add(new BookingVariant() 
        { Title = "Title2", BookingVariantURL = "myURL2" });

        this.BookingVariants.Add(new BookingVariant() 
        { Title = "Title3", BookingVariantURL = "myURL3" });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<BookingVariant> BookingVariants
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}
```

In the calling class you define the data context like this:

```
MyData dataObject = new MyData();
BookingVariantsListView.DataContext = dataObject;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not the problem. The context is set correctly. The Listview renders the correct number of rows. But the columns to not show the content of the properties, but only the class' name

Comment: The column header shows the class name or does each cell show the class name?

Comment: Each row. The cells don’t seems to be created at all.

Comment: I still believe it is a problem with your data context can please add a snippet with your code where you assign the data context.

Comment: see the added image. the data context of the listview is fine. If i add a ToString method to my model, it is used to fill the rows. So it has to deal with the DisplayMemberBinding. I am missing something.